# Without polling, is there a way for another thread to "reset" a sleeping thread's timer, causing it to sleep longer?

Tags: linux, multithreading, language-agnostic

Suppose we have two threads, A and B. B is doing some action periodically, and A is set to sleep until a certain time. I want B to be able to call a function `keepSleeping(A)`, which will cause A's sleep timer to be extended. If `keepSleeping(A)` is not called, A should eventually wake up.

**On Linux, is there a way to implement this *without* periodically waking up A to check if `keepSleeping` has been called?**

[Resetting sleeping time of a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292820/resetting-sleeping-time-of-a-thread) asks a similar question, but I want to know if there is a more elegant solution that doesn't involve A waking up when it doesn't have to.

Comment: If you are talking about Thread::sleep, then the answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no.  If thread A has called `sleep()` or `usleep()` or similar, then it's going to wake up at the appointed time, and there's nothing another thread can do to stop it.  Of course you can have thread A immediately go back to sleep again if you want, so it shouldn't be a big deal.

That said, if you don't want thread A to wake up at all (except when B wants it to), then a way to obtain that behavior would be to have thread A block on a [condition-variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead of inside a `sleep()` call.  In this design, thread A would remain asleep indefinitely until thread B signals the condition variable, at which point thread A would wake up, do its thing, and then block on the condition variable again.  That would allow thread B full control over when-and-if thread A wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

> Without polling, is there a way for another thread to “reset” a sleeping thread's timer, causing it to sleep longer?

If you are talking about `Thread.sleep`, then there is no way.  If A calls `Thread.sleep(timeout)` then it won't wake up until after the timeout has expired.  You can wake it up earlier by interrupting the thread.  But you can't cause it to *not wake up* until later.

You could potentially *reduce* the number of unwanted thread wakeups by using using wait / notify and implementing a single "sleep manager" thread to perform the notifications.  The manager could use a timed wait or sleep to wait for the next thing it needs to do.

Caveats:

- In your scenario, it might wake up and find that it didn't need to do anything.
- If you wanted to get make a worker thread wake up *earlier* than originally scheduled, you may need to interrupt the sleep manager thread.  Or just interrupt the worker thread directly.

It you use interrupts like this, you need to be sure that it doesn't interfere with (potential) other uses of interrupts.  This adds to the complexity.

Is the complexity worth it?  (IMO), only if you need to change wakeup times frequently.

In your scenario, the simple approach is to just let the wakeups happen and have the worker thread go back to sleep with the updated wake time.